# placing the full width table caption on top of the table in tufte-latex book

Tags: tables, captions, tufte

I am using tufte-latex book format for writing my thesis. I have a full width table which I can easily define within `table*` environment in tufte book. As far as I understood, the caption should also be full width. However, I still get it on the right margin. Any idea how to solve this issue? I also want the caption to be placed on the top of the table.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[nols,a4paper,justified,marginals=auto]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{here I have a long caption that I want it to be in the fullwidth format as the table but I get it in margin.\label{table3}}%
    \begin{tabular}{llllllllllllllllllll}%
      A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P\\%
     0.50&$0.47^{a}$&0.48&0.50&0.47&0.48&0.60&0.39&1.00&\0.48&0.50&0.47&0.48&0.60&0.39&1.00\%
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
       %\footnotesize
       \item $^{a}$ some extra information about this number.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably unrelated to your main question but two-column tables can not be `h` so `\begin{table*}[h!]` can not be placed at all by latex so would (I assume) always go to the end of the document (or next `\clearpage`) delete `[h!]`.

Comment: Hi! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`: this will help us help you!

Comment: It is now edited and compilable! @ebo

Comment: It is solved now! @ebo